# Django 'on_upload' Cyrillic symbols error

Tags: python, django

I have my book model in `models.py`, that contains title as `CharField`:

```
title = models.CharField(
    verbose_name = "Название книги",
    max_length = 75,
    null = False,
    unique = True
    )
```

Also, I'm using [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) to track this, and other fields changes.

When I'm trying to add book with title `Колобок`, I got this error:

```
'locale' codec can't encode character '\u041a' in position 0: encoding error
```

I'm afraid that, if I type anything in other fields of this model in Cyrillic, it throws me same error.

---

Also, in my `models.py` I have model for `Author` with 1 field:

```
author = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False)
```

But, in this case, I have no error. I think it `django-model-utils`'s problem.

---

UPD 1:

error trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/library/book/add/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'library.apps.LibraryConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1634.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1522.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1561.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_model
  1088.         obj.save()

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\model_utils\tracker.py" in save
  243.             ret = original_save(instance, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\model_utils\tracker.py" in save
  243.             ret = original_save(instance, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1334.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1277.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_save_val
  1228.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
  288.             file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in save
  86.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)

File "c:\Users\yuyuko\Documents\dev\project3\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in generate_filename
  305.             dirname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(self.upload_to)

Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/library/book/add/
Exception Value: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u041a' in position 0: encoding error
```

UPD 2:

I noticed that if I create record only in ENG language, it don't throw that encode error. And, if I rename this book later to Cyrillic, it also don't throw me an error. So, it throws me that error only on `model` create. Any suggests what I can do with it?

UPD 3:

So, I decided to look inside of `...\django\db\models\fields\files.py` file and found function that thorws me an error. Function name is `generate_filename`.

From this function documentation

> Apply (if callable) or prepend (if a string) upload_to to the filename ...

I think that it would be nice to insert a `try except`, and, it finally passes me. My edited part of this function looks like this:

```
try:
    dirname = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(self.upload_to)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    dirname = self.upload_to
```

If someone understood Django a lot, will this change breaks anything? And, how now I should implement this change to my project file, not venv's Django?

UPD 4:

At start of this question I think that problem in [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils) now, when I edited Django's source code, I think that's Django problem.

Comment: can you add more of the error trace and the code where the error occurs

Comment: @ger.s.brett added error trace. what code should i add? i adding book via standart django's admin panel.

Comment: The error is coming from a file upload. Do you have a file field on the model?